# May thebibliography environment provide APA-style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

Using a minimal template `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}`, suppose I  want the following in the text:

> As (Gettier, 1963), 122, points out.

Suppose moreover, that I want the following in the bibliography:

> Gettier, E. (1963) Is Justified True Belief Knowledge? *Analysis*, 23(6):121-123.

By means of

```
As \cite{Gettier1963}, p. 122, points out, 

\begin{thebibliography}{11}

\bibitem[Gettier, 1963]{Gettier1963}
\noindent Is Justified True Belief Knowledge? 
\emph{Analysis},  23 (6):121-123.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I get:

> As [Gettier, 1963], 122, points out. in the text, and [Gettier, 1963] Is Justified True Belief Knowledge? *Analysis*, 23(6):121-123. in the bibliography.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter \def\@biblabel#1{#1} \makeatother 



\begin{document}

\nocite{Gettier1963}(Gettier, 1963) is a famous article in modern epistemology. 


\begin{thebibliography}{11}

\bibitem[Gettier, E. (1963)]{Gettier1963} ``Is Justified True Belief Knowledge?'' 
In \emph{Analysis},  23 (6):121-123. 
    
\end{thebibliography}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure about all that? Wouldn't it usually be  „As E. Gettier (1963, p. 122) pointed out …“ or similar? Either way, please show as a minimal working example.

Comment: @Ingmar I showed the code I used, so in this context that is the mwe, which can be used in virtually all document structures.

Something like your (E. Gettier, 1963, 122) might be preferable. But that is a separate point, which should be treated on its own.

Comment: No, an MWE is a fully contained _working_ example that we can compile and run. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that At this point we don't even know what document class you are using; BibTeX/BibLaTeX, what have you …

Comment: I know very well what an mwe is. I said that in **this context** that is the mwe, which can be used in virtually all document structures. The point is that what document structure you make use of does not matter. So use a minimal one: \documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}. BibTeX and BibLatTeX are excluded here, as the title, and my code for a manual bibliography indicate.

Comment: So you're doing the bibliography manually? The parentheses are usually controlled by your bibliography package. And the style you're showing in the bibliography itself seems very non-standard; items are usually formatted last name first (at least for the first author), and the author and year are not usually in brackets/parentheses together (usually just the year).  Can you point to a particular place where this style is described?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, I do it manually. I had too many head aches with the alternatives, and I usually do not have many citations.

I used both author and year in brackets, in the in-line citation as well as in the bibliography, on account of the limitations imposed by the program. 

It may indeed be better to use the last name before the first name.

May any of these alternatives facilitate a solution to avoid the []-brackets, which I do not find very natural?

Comment: Instead of adding an "edit" explaining that you prefer your answer the more natural way is to accept your answer. References to answers in the question itself are always a bit ... meh. (There is a waiting period of 48 hours before you can accept your own answer, but I think that should be over now.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks. Yes, I was waiting for the period to lapse, so I accepted now.  At any rate, what I did works very well, so I recommend it!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To make matters clearer, I write up an answer. Most of what I write here can also be found in some of the comments.

Use a minimal template

```
\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document},
```

and do the bibliography manually. Put

```
\bibitem[Gettier, E. (1963)]{Gettier1963}
```

in the bibliography.

Next, put

```
\makeatletter \def\@biblabel#1{#1} \makeatother
```

in the preamble, to get rid of the square brackets

```
[Gettier, E (1963)]
```

in the bibliography.

Next, when citing in the text, write

```
\nocite{Gettier1963}(Gettier, 1963).
```

We may continue like this for other items to obtain a bibliography and reference-style which abides by the APA-guidelines.

Comment: Try to format the code parts as code to help with readability.  See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: @user202729 There is no code part in my answer, which you just commented. \makeatletter \def@biblabel#1{#1} \makeatother is literally what you put in the preamble.

Comment: The preamble contains code and `\makeatletter` definitly fulfills the definition of being code, thus program instructions.

Comment: @Roland So, what is your point?

Comment: My point is that your statement "There is no code part in my answer" is incorrect and the comment of @user202729 has its justification .

Comment: @Roland We identify codes contextually, and my comment was related to the codes user202729 referred to. All of our language use makes use of codes, of course. At any rate, I do not see how I can improve upon the answer I gave, or other statements I uttered, by formatting codes.

Comment: I do not really know what you are talking about with “language use”. I am referring to LaTeX code in your answer ( e.g. \makeatletter or \nocite{Gettier1963}) which is LaTeX code and thus should/could be formatted as the link, provided by user202729, explains. This would at least make your answer more readable.

Comment: @Roland Do you suggest to format a command as \nocite{Getterier1963}? Feel free to do so, with the codes user202729 linked to.

Comment: So, did I format it correctly?

Comment: In my opinion it is now much more readable, yes.

Answer (score 10):

Without using any bibliography package or using BibTeX, the default definition of `\@biblabel` and `\@cite` are:

```
\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]}
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
```

So if you merely want to change the remove the brackets or and change the citations  to use parentheses, you can add the following to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{#1}
\def\@cite#1#2{({#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi})}
\makeatother
```

### Why you should not do this

What you're asking to do will give you far more headaches than using BiBTeX and a proper bibliography package `natbib` or `biblatex`. To see this consider the fact that the element inside the label in the bibliography should contain the author(s)' names and initials, followed by the date, but the citation callout in the text should usually just show the author(s)' last name without the initials. So you're trying to imitate quite complicated formatting manually, and you will likely fail as a result.   For example, your in text citation for the article you in your example should be:

(Gettier, 1963) or Gettier (1963)

but the bibliography should be:

Gettier, E., 1963  Is Justified True Belief Knowledge? *Analysis*, 23(6):121-123.

There are many Author/Year bibliography styles around that should work for you. You claim to have problems with them, but it seems like you should ask about solving those problems instead of trying to (badly) reinvent the wheel by doing things manually.

Comment: You succeeded with changing from [] to () in the bibliography, which is great! Thanks!

Comment: May one (1) have the same change from [] to () in the in-line citation, and perhaps (2) at the same time (2) get rid of the parentheses altogether in the bibliography?

Comment: I solved my question (2) by writing \makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{#1}
\makeatother

Comment: That leaves only (1) unaccounted for. :)

Comment: At any rate, I succeeded with what I wanted, in a somewhat roundabout way. I put \bibitem[Gettier, E. (1963)]{Gettier1963}, and get rid of the square parentheses in the bibliography by means of \makeatletter \def\@biblabel#1{#1} \makeatother. I use \nocite{Gettier1963}(Gettier, 1963) when I want to refer to Gettier's paper in the text. With this little work-around, I obtain the desired output! :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: At this point it is clear to me that my purposes are best served by using the algorithm I present in my answer. So I will not adopt natbib or biblatex.

Answer (score 4):

In principle `thebibliography` is little more than an `enumerate` list with some additional syntactic sugar. `\bibitem` works pretty much like `\item` in `enumerate` with the addition that its mandatory argument defines an implicit label (similar to `\label`) that can later be referenced.

`\cite` then is pretty much a `\ref` to the `\label` implied by `\bibitem`.

The standard `thebibliography`/`\bibitem` combination will generate numeric citation labels.

Just like with `enumerate` and `\item` you can use the optional argument of `\bibitem` to force a particular label that does not follow the usual numbering scheme.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{Gettier1963}

\begin{thebibliography}{MyOwnLabel}
\bibitem[MyOwnLabel]{Gettier1963}
Gettier, E. (1963). ``Is Justified True Belief Knowledge?'' 
In \emph{Analysis}, 23 (6):121-123.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: [MyOwnLabel]]

With this simple setup you will only ever realistically have one (automatic) way to cite each work.

But there are ways to offer more citation options.

APA style for example has broadly speaking two ways of referencing

- narrative citations of the form `<author> (<year>)`, e.g. "Gettier (1963)"
- parenthetical citations of the form `(<author>, <year>)`, e.g. "(Gettier, 1963)"

crucially citations always consist of the same data (author and year) just presented in different ways.

The idea is now to use the optional argument of `\bibitem` not to force a specific output, but to pass the author and year data on to LaTeX so that several different cite commands can use these two pieces of information to print the different citation styles.

This is what `natbib` does. Indeed while `natbib` is most often used together with BibTeX (and its `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle`) commands, it need not be and can be used together with a manually curated `thebibliography` environment.

`natbib.sty` explains the format `\bibitem` expects

```latex
 % If author-year citations are selected, \bibitem must have one of the
 %   following forms:
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al., 1990]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones
 %       et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\astroncite{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citename{Jones et al., }1990]{key}...
 %   \harvarditem[Jones et al.]{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{1990}{key}...
 %
 % This is either to be made up manually, or to be generated by an
 % appropriate .bst file with BibTeX.
```

`natbib` then defines (amongst other commands) the two commands `\citet` and `\citep` in analogy to APA's narrative and parenthetical citations.

Thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{Gettier1963}

\citet{Gettier1963}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Gettier(1963)]{Gettier1963}
Gettier, E. (1963). ``Is Justified True Belief Knowledge?'' 
In \emph{Analysis}, 23 (6):121-123.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: (Gettier, 1963) Gettier (1963)]

For APA style there is the added complication that the delimiter between authors changes depending on whether you are in `\citet` or `\citep`. With some tricks that can be faked as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\myand}{%
  \ifNAT@swa
  \&%
  \else
  and%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\citep{Gettier1963}

\citet{Gettier1963}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Gettier \myand\ Bettier(1963)]{Gettier1963}
Gettier, E. \& Bettier, B. (1963). ``Is Justified True Belief Knowledge?'' 
In \emph{Analysis}, 23 (6):121-123.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Gettier & Bettier, 1963) Gettier and Bettier (1963)]

So even if you use a manual `thebibliography` there are ways to have different in-text citation styles.

---

The strength of BibTeX is that it automatically sorts your references and allows you to input only the raw data for the entry. The tedious formatting is taken care of by the BibTeX styles.

Comment: "With this simple setup you will only ever realistically have one way to cite each work."

At the step:

Next, when citing in the text, write

\nocite{Gettier1963}(Gettier, 1963).,

my answer shows  how to cite each work just as you want.

Comment: Notice that I put \makeatletter \def\@biblabel#1{#1} \makeatother 
 in the preamble to get rid of the []-parentheses you had on [MyOwnLabel].

Comment: "The strength of BibTeX is that it automatically sorts your references and allows you to input only the raw data for the entry. The tedious formatting is taken care of by the BibTeX styles." My bibliographies are so short that it is not strainful.