# How can I remove the numbers but keep the indents in my bibliography? But without using BibTex, just manually in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\label{AJ91}
\bibitem{AJ91}Angrist, J. and Krueger, A. (1991). \textit{Does compulsory school attendance affect schooling and earnings?} Quarterly Journal of Economics, \textbf{106}(4), 979--1014.

\label{BP88}
\bibitem{BP88}Bairoch, P. (1988). \textit{Cities and Economic Development: From the Dawn of History to the Present}. Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

\label{BC07}
\bibitem{BC07}Brokaw, C. (2007). \textit{Commerce in Culture: The Sibao Book Trade in the Qing and Republican Periods}. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Asia Center.

\label{CC55}
\bibitem{CC55}Chang, C. (1955). \textit{The Chinese Gentry: Studies on Their Role in Nineteenth-Century Chinese Society}. Seattle: University of Washington Press.

\end{thebibliography}
```

And the output is like this:

[image]

BUT I want it to look like this, so without numbers, but with indent:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In principle `thebibliography` is just a fancy `enumerate` environment and `\bibitem`/`\cite` are like `\label`/`\ref` with an option to override the label output. (Usually they will produce numbered citations, but if you use the optional argument of `\bibitem`, i.e. `\bibitem[<label>]{<key>}` the entry `<key>` will be cited as "[`<label>`]" in the text.)

The list formatting (indentation, distance between items etc.) of the reference list produced by `thebibliography` is primarily controlled by your document class. Additional packages like `natbib` (which can be used without BibTeX and with a manual `thebibliography`) might take over and change things.

If you want author-year in text-citations and a suitable author-year bibliography without numbers (but with indentation), you can try to load the `apalike` package. It was originally intended to be used with BibTeX's `apalike` style, but can also be used with a manual `thebibliography`.

That package changes both the bibliography list environment `thebibliography` and the output of `\cite` to work better for author-year citations. You just need to give the desired citation output in the optional argument of `\bibitem` (and fiddle with `\@cite` to remove some brackets).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{apalike}
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{AJ91}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Angrist and Krueger (1991)]{AJ91}Angrist, J. and Krueger, A. (1991). \textit{Does compulsory school attendance affect schooling and earnings?} Quarterly Journal of Economics, \textbf{106}(4), 979--1014.

\bibitem[Bairoch (1988)]{BP88}Bairoch, P. (1988). \textit{Cities and Economic Development: From the Dawn of History to the Present}. Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

\bibitem[Brokaw (2007)]{BC07}Brokaw, C. (2007). \textit{Commerce in Culture: The Sibao Book Trade in the Qing and Republican Periods}. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Asia Center.

\bibitem[Chang (1955)]{CC55}Chang, C. (1955). \textit{The Chinese Gentry: Studies on Their Role in Nineteenth-Century Chinese Society}. Seattle: University of Washington Press.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Angrist and Krueger (1991)]

If you want finer control over citations and an option to cite both "(`<author>`, `<year>`)" and "`<author>` (`<year>`)", you can make your `thebibliography` compatible with `natbib` as described in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624416/35864) to [May thebibliography environment provide APA-style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623718/35864).